# Firebase Realtime Database - Write if user is not in the User ID list OR if it is then if the newData.Val() is less than the data.Val()

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to

- if a user is not in the userID list to let him write his time( this only happens the first time - regardless his score)
- after that if his new time is less than his current time let him write to the database.

is there a way to do this? Can anyone help me ?

Unfortunately i cannot make it work. I have only succeed to the part to check the old value and the new value. This works  But ONLY this if the user is ALREADY registered in the database.

I also tried to add the !data.exists but it is not working .

Below my rules

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
      "Users" : {
           "3X3": {
             "$userID": {
               ".write": "data.child('time').val() > newData.child('time').val()"
             }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
      "Users" : {
           "3X3": {
             "$userID": {
               ".write": "
                 !data.exists() || // 
                 data.child('time').val() > newData.child('time').val()
               "
             }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [new vs existing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data) in security rules.

Comment: thanks a lot! I did not have the chance to thank you